# I'm writing a very simple letter grading system, are if statements the most efficient?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, if-statement, switch-statement

Code example:

```
question:
cout << "Enter the grade % you scored on the test: ";
cin >> userScore;

if (userScore == 100) {
    cout << "You got a perfect score!" << endl;
}   
else if (userScore >= 90 && userScore < 100) {
    cout << "You scored an A." << endl;
}
else if (userScore >= 80 && userScore < 89) {
    cout << "You scored a B." << endl;
}
//... and so on...
else if (userScore >= 0 && userScore < 59) {
    cout << "You scored an F." << endl;
}
goto question;
```

This code has a total of 6 if statements, and it looks very.. cookie-cutter-ish.. I guess? Is there a more efficient/optimal way to write this?

I looked up some example beginner projects for C++ and found [this grading one](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/12974/), and it said knowledge of switch statements would be useful. I looked into that and my understanding is that, in this case, switch statements would effectively work the same way as if statements.

Comment: If I were grading this I would deduct points for using a `goto` instead of a loop. The rest would be fine.

Comment: Haha, thanks. The `goto` here was just to make it easier for me to test :P Is there a negative stigma about using them?

Comment: Also when you are beginning to learn the words ***most efficient*** should not ever be used. Usually you profile before you attempt to rewrite code for efficiency. And you only do so if any significant gain can be made. I can tell you it won't happen with this code. You are talking about saving a few nano seconds maybe a few hundred nano seconds. Write code for readability over this type of optimization.

Comment: If you check for invalid scores (>100) once at the beginning, you don't need to check for e.g. <89, <79, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a function to calculate the letter. Like this:

```
char score(int s) {
  if (s < 60)
    return 'F';
  return (9 - s / 10) + 'A';
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
  int userScore;
  std::cout << "Enter the grade % you scored on the test: ";
  std::cin >> userScore;
  if (userScore < 0 || userScore > 100)
    std::cout << "Invalid\n";
  else if (userScore == 100)
    std::cout << "You got a perfect score!\n";
  else    
   std::cout << "You scored a(n) " << score(userScore) << ".\n";     
}
```

Comment: good code you will never get an F you will always get an E (Exceptional) :)